# Automate browser in iOS UIwebview

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

How would I automate (automatically click what I need with speed in mind) the UIwebview in iOS?  Could I use javascript?  Thanks

Comment: See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I am sorry I am really new to developing iOS apps.  In the webview of my app I want the app to tap certain things automatically as fast as possible.  These things would be set before the webview is opened.  Just unsure how I would go about this in xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the best choice is to work with JavaScript.

You can implement the UIWebViewDelegate method webViewDidFinnishLoad: in your UIViewController subclass and then you call:

```
[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"your javascript code goes here"];
```

This will simply return a NSString, if you need.

If you need more control, like calling JavaScript functions from Objective-C, or calling Objective-C methods from JavaScript, you can try https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge